# Why is core.js not loaded in Joomla 3?

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla2.5, migrate, joomla3.4

I am migrating my own Joomla component from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3. Some of the buttons use javascript `Joomla.submitform()`, which was defined in \media\system\js\core.js, but somehow this file is not loaded any more now...

I could simply add `JFactory::getDocument()->addScript( JURI::root().'media/system/js/core.js' )` to my component's code, but that seems the quick and dirty way to me.

Could someone tell me what the nice and clean way is? Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy as pie

```
JHtmlBehaviour::core();
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets added when you use the line `JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');`. This also adds punycode.js and validate.js.

All front-end core components that call submitform() seem to add this in their default.php file.

The following are the places where I found it in the front-end:

- \components\com_config\view\config\tmpl\default.php
- \components\com_config\view\modules\tmpl\default.php
- \components\com_config\view\templates\tmpl\default.php
- \components\com_content\views\form\tmpl\edit.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding the form validator behavior would still be a kind of dirty work around when I do not need the form validation functionality. In other places, for example in \adminstrator\com_banners\views\banner\tmpl\edit.php, `Joomla.submitform()` is defined in the template file itself by calling `JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration()`... :s